# Bootstrap with DataTable integration design issue PHP

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I'm using latest version of twitter bootstrap v.3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com/) and integrating the same with dataTables (https://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2)

The files and versions are as follows:

1. bootstrap.css           -   v.3.1.1
2. bootstrap.min.js        -   v.3.1.1
3. jquery.dataTables.js    -   v.1.9.4
4. DT_bootstrap.js         -   Not given

If I use the above file, the pagination, search and sorting are working fine. But the design is shuffled (i.e search box, page numbers etc.. are looking ugly without any style applied).

I can over-come the design issues if I change the bootstrap.css-v.3.1.1 to bootstrap.min.css-v.2.3.2 but my header, footer and other designs are getting collapsed.

When I analyzed both the css i.e. 3.1.1 and 2.3.2 - I came to know that many class files are missing in 3.1.1.
The one such missing class files are .span6(and still there are lot more) from my knowledge.

Now, How to fix the design issue or where shall I find the updated one.

Have anyone came across this issue?

Comment: if I ask any question related to twitter bootstrap there is no reply from anyone. i have asked many. is this not the right place to ask question related to bootstrap. yes?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/Jowin/Datatables-Bootstrap3

Comment: Same issue here, can someone help? I tried the above solution but that does not fix it, also the official solution seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete example in the official documentation of how to use Datatables with Bootstrap 3 :
https://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/bootstrap.html